# Trigger event on PWA iOS splash screen

Tags: ios, events, triggers, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

Are there some events that can be triggered during/after splash screen appearing on standalone iOS progressive web app (PWA)? Which event would be the most suitable to execute code just after the PWA shows up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following javascript code to call a function after your splashscreen disappears:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // Your code
});
```

However, you cannot call a function when the splashscreen appears, as the splashscreen is a placeholder while your website loads and therefore, your website wouldn't even be available while the splashscreen is active.